# How Does the Multiple Return Syntax Work?

Tags: python, syntax

I have a problem where I want to return a value based on a result. But to accomplish that, I would need to have multiple return statements like this:

```py
if w1 > w2: return 'Computer Wins!!'
elif w1 == w2: return 'Tie War!!'
else:
    return 'I Win!!'
```

But I saw someone syntax like this:

```py
return ('I Win!!', 'Computer Wins!!', 'Tie War!!')[(w1>w2)-(w1==w2)]
```

So, I am not sure how the second piece of code works. Can you please explain it? Thanks!

Comment: Which piece of code is not good practice? I just want to know how it works! That's all. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second method is clever but I would not recommend it for readability sake:

Let’s break the code down

```py
return ('I Win!!', 'Computer Wins!!', 'Tie War!!')[(w1>w2)-(w1==w2)]
```

**Note**: `True` evaluates to `1` and `False` to `0` in Python.

#### Cases

If `(w1 > w2)` is True(1) then necessarily  `(w1 == w2)` is False(0)
->  [(w1 > w2) - (w1 == w2)]
->  [1 - 0] equals [1]
->  Therefore `('I Win!!', 'Computer Wins!!', 'Tie War!!')[1]`
->  Results is `'Computer Win!!'`

If `(w1 > w2)` is False(0) then necessarily  `(w1 == w2)` is False(0)
->  [(w1 > w2) - (w1 == w2)]
->  [0 - 0] equals [0]
->  Thus `('I Win!!', 'Computer Wins!!', 'Tie War!!')[0]`
->  Results is `'I win!'`

If `(w1 > w2)` is False(0) and `(w1 == w2)` True (1) then
->  [(w1 > w2) - (w1 == w2)]
->  [0 - 1] equals [-1]
so  `('I Win!!', 'Computer Wins!!', 'Tie War!!')[-1]` gives the last item, namely `'Tie War!!'`

Comment: Oh! I see! I fully understand it now. Just want to make one thing clear, the deciding factor of which is True or False comes from the function right? Other than that, a great explanation. Thanks!

Comment: From the values expression of w1 and w2. E.g w1 = 9, w2 = 3, w1 > w2, 9 > 3, True

Answer (score 2):

This expression builds a `tuple` with all three return values, and accesses the right return value by performing a subtraction on `bool`s. It is using the fact that arithmetic operations in Python interpret `True` as 1 and `False` as 0.

For a computer win, `w1>w2` is true, and `w1==w2` is false, so `(w1>w2) - (w1==w2)` = 1 - 0 = 1, and the element at position 1 of the tuple is returned.

For a tie, the result of the operation is -1 following the same logic, so the last element of the tuple is returned. In the same fashion, for a player win, the operation evaluates to 0, so the first element of the tuple is returned.

This is considered bad practice because it is much harder to read than using if/elif/else statements, as verified by you having to ask this question to understand the logic!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Altareos, but I still don't fully understand. I am starting to get an idea from your answer, but I still don't get it. It's quite complex to understand like you said.